# Show that the set is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Show that the set $P=\left\{x \in X: f(x)\in \mathbb{R} \right\} $ is measurable.

My solution:

$P=\left\{x \in X: f(x)\in \mathbb{R} \right\}= \left\{x \in X: \exists _{M \in \mathbb{R}} f(x)<M \right\}=\bigcup_{M \in \mathbb{R}}\left\{x \in X: f(x)<M\right\}$

Is is correct?

Comment: Which topological space does $f$ go to? Is $f$ measurable?

Comment: First of all: what do we know about $f$?  Second: we can only guarantee the measurability of a *countable* union of measurable sets.

Comment: You need to specify some more information on what the measure space is and what conditions $f$ satisfies. One could easily construct examples with a function which is zero on a non-measurable set and infinity otherwise on $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ which would have $P$ not be measurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $f:X \to \bar {\Bbb R}$ is measurable.

Then, it suffices to note that
$$
P = \bigcup_{N \in \Bbb N}[\{x\in X:f(x) > -N\} \cap \{x\in X:f(x) < N\}]
$$
note that this is a *countable* union.

Comment: How did you get this? Can I ask for some more details?

Comment: First, can you tell me if my assumption is correct? Second, what exactly is it that you're asking about?  Are you asking why the union on the right is equal to set $P$, or are you specifically asking *how I got* this expression?

Comment: Yes. Your assumption is correct. Can I explain me the soltuion?

Comment: What exactly is it that you're asking about?

Comment: why did you chose natural numbers instead of real numbers?

Comment: I guess that only countable union of measurable sets is mesurable and we can't tell the same about uncountable union of...

Comment: That's right. ${}$

Comment: but why can't we write: $\bigcup_{N \in \mathbb{N}}\left\{x \in X: f(x)<N\right\}$?

Comment: What if $f(x) = -\infty$?

Comment: I do not know..

Comment: Well, if $f(x) = -\infty$, then $f(x) \notin \Bbb R$.  So, we have to exclude that possibility, just as we have to exclude the possibility of $f(x) = \infty$.

Comment: Ah I see. We made the assumption at the begining. but  is it possible to change this assumption that $f(x) \in \mathbb{R} \cup \left\{ +  \infty \right\}$

Comment: Not without changing the problem statement. Or, you could use the fact that if $f$ is measurable, then $|f|$ is measurable.

Comment: Yes. This is what I mean. How would look the solution If I change the problem statment?

Comment: How about you decide which problem you want me to solve, *edit your question accordingly*, and then I'll answer it

Comment: The first solution is enough. Thank you for your help and patience!